# output to stream float numbers with precision

Tags: c++, stream, numbers, precision

I have a problem with float numbers precision:

```
int main(void) {
  double b = 106.829599;
  float a = b;
  std::cerr << std::setprecision(6) << "a = " << a << "; b = " << b << std::endl;
  std::cerr << std::setprecision(7) << "a = " << a << "; b = " << b << std::endl;
}
```

result is:

> a = 106.83; b = 106.83
>
> a = 106.8296; b = 106.8296

So, my question is why numbers in first line are so short (I was expecting to see 106.829)

gcc 4.1.2, also I made a test at [LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1040f80065e51e9e0e7fee838f991542)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, 106.829599 rounded to 6 digits (3 decimals) is 106.830, which is displayed as 106.83 since 6 digits precision given to [setprecision](https://cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) is only a maximum value.

> The decimal precision determines the *maximum number of digits* to be
> written on insertion operations to express floating-point values.

What you may be looking for is combining setprecision with [fixed](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/).