# What is the C++ equivalent of the c float precision command?

Tags: c++, c, format-string

In C we have a statement like:

```
printf("%6.3f ",floatNumber);
```

which limits the number of digits when printing.
How can I achieve the similar behavior in `C++` ? i know of `setprecision` but that doesn't help me do the same exact thing.

Comment: The C++ standard library includes `printf` as well.  For a modern C++ way, see `boost::format`.  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/format/example/sample_formats.cpp

Comment: `precision` and `fixed` need to be set in combination for a fixed, specified number of places to the right of the decimal.

Comment: relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030329/output-to-stream-float-numbers-with-precision Take a look at `std::fixed`

Comment: Why don't you use `cout<<setprecision(XXX)<<floatNumber;`?

Comment: Also, that format string doesn't limit the number of digits.  http://ideone.com/wllX3C

Comment: @Maroun it isn't guaranteed to output XXX digits

Comment: @BenVoigt:Thanks,But i'm looking for something that can be achieved using the standard libraries (if we have any),so that i can tell others who dont know about boost and cant figure out how to use it.I didnt try to use the c commands (libraries) intentionally , i want to know if there is a pure C++ of doing it.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz:Thanks,But thats not what exactly im after,actually i am trying to see if i can limit the numbers(Format them) when i want to print them,that just doesnt address my problem from the where i look at it.

Comment: Nitpick: The `"%6.3f"` is a format specifier, not a *command*, and it is not C, but a `printf` format specifier (also available in C++). Being precise in the wording helps communication.

Comment: @David: I suspect he's referring to the `printf` function, not the format specifier, when he says *command*.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Same thing, then it would not be the *command* but the function call... :) I am a strong believer that misuse of the language leads to many confusions that could be easily avoided if people *learnt* and used the correct terms. I am not *bitching* about the misuse (in case I might have given that impression), but rather trying to provide a better terms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a similar format to that specified by `%6.3f` using just the standard iostream manipulators you can do:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setw(6) << std::setprecision(3) << f;
```

Specifically `std::fixed` indicates the same basic format as `f` in the format string so that, for example, 'precision' means the same thing for both the format string and the ostream. `std::setprecision(3)` then actually sets the precision and `std::setw(6)` sets the field width. Without setting `std::fixed` you'd get a format similar to that specified by the format string `"%6.3g"`.

Note that except for `setw` these manipulators are sticky. That is, they remain in effect after the one variable is output.

Answer (score 4):

Your best option would be to use `boost::format`.  See [the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/format/), especially [the examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/format/example/sample_formats.cpp)

Next best (if you can't use `boost` in your project) is to keep using `printf`.  It's part of the C++ Standard Library so it should "just work" as long as you `#include <stdio.h>` just like always.

Comment: Thanks but I didnt try to use the c libraries intentionally , i want to know if there is a pure C++ of doing it.

Comment: @Hossein: There is no "pure C++". The C++ standard *includes* the C standard library explicitly, and many of the iostream and string functions are *mandated* to use `sprintf` for formatting. Nobody is looking down on you for using `printf`.

Comment: @Hossein You can however use `std::printf` from `<cstdio>`, which indeed is the non-deprecated *"pure C++"* version of the deprecated `printf` from `<stdio.h>`, and thus isn't any less *"pure"* than `std::ostream` or whatever (in the end `<stdio.h>` isn't any less *"pure"* either, since C++ includes the C library, it's just that it is deprecated, whatever that means in practice (probably nothing)).

Comment: I have heard that we should do everything in c++ way, if we want to use strings,use string ,and there are lots of other functions in C ,that is told to get away from them and use the C++ counter part (such as itoa?),So that's my first intention of asking such question.So you mean we don't have everything in the C++ way,And still there are situations that we must the c library? I thought the existence of those libraries were solely because of the backward compatibility with c source codes, not that C++ is split into two sections -the C++ standard library and C standard library?

Comment: @Hossein We can get very close to `printf`, by using many of the stream manipulators to our advantage, like `std::setw` or `std::setprecision`, but unfortunately in your particular case the *exact* behaviour seems not to be reproducible. In the end `printf` in particular is a very powerful function (and likewise very dangeruous, too). But it may be the case that you cannot reproduce every little aspect of the C library by according *"pure"* C++ libraries (whatever that means) one-to-one, some things are just done differently, that's why the C library is *part* of C++.

Comment: @Hossein Take for example the C function `remove`. It may seem there is no *"pure C++"* function to mimic that (until `<filesystem>` is added to the standard). But you know what, there actually is, `std::remove` (from `<cstdio>`, not from `<algorithm>`), which does exactly the same thing and isn't any less *"pure"* than the hypothetical `<filesystem>`. It just works differently and the style may not fit to the rest of your *"pure C++"* code, but it is perfectly part of *"pure C++"* and gets the job done.

Comment: I follow Alexander Stepanov's advice, "When we program in C++ we should not be ashamed of its C heritage, but make full use of it" ( http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf , page 10).  If you're not familiar with Stepanov, he was on the three-person team that designed and implemented the STL.

Comment: Thank you all guys,I really appreciate these information.i really do:) and im greatful for that.its really good to know.Thanks again specially you @ChristianRau :)